# Is it possible to alter a recurring price that an existing customer is charged with Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

If an Express Connect Account holder creates a Product with a Recurring Price of say $10/month.  And a customer signs up for this, a Subscription is created and Stripe will automatically bill the customer $10/month until they cancel.  So here is my question...if the Connect Account holder wants to increase their Price from $10/month to say $12/month...can they do this such that the price increase will be billed to existing customers as well as new customers?  I am thinking of an example where the Connected Account has say 100 existing subscribers, so manually changing each one, doesn't really work.  Looking for something automated.  From what I have read, it seems, that only new customers will see the new $12/month Price, and existing customers will see the original $10/month price until they cancel. Is this correct?  Seems odd that Stripe would have no way of allowing Connect Account holders a way to increase their recurring Prices for existing users.  I get they can create a new price..and hope users voluntarily switch to the new high price, but that seems odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to think Subscription as per-customer object. Let's say you have 100 existing Customers already subscribed to a $10 monthly plan, there are 100 existing Subscriptions object, tights to each of those Customers.

Now if the Connected Account created a new price of $12/month, all new Customers will subscribe to this new price, and create separated new Subscription objects.

If you want to upgrade the currently existing Subscriptions, you would need to update each of them, changing the old price to the new price, by Stripe's [Subscription Update API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update). Make sure to read the note about Proration, or refer to [Proration Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations)

Comment: Thanks orakaro.  Your understanding is exactly the same as mine.  You are right, that you can use the Subscription API, but you would still need to go in and change each one individually.  With over a 100 Subscriptions, that is not really what I am looking for.  I think the answer is simple:  there is no real way to change a recurring price.  Work arounds exist, but nothing in the Stripe API library to handle this.  I was hoping someone from Stripe would respond but I believe this is not a coding issue...its more about legal compliance, as to why it is the way it is.

Comment: @KevinK fwiw, there is a subscription update api that can assign the new "price" object to the subscriptions, and you can choose to prorate or not the subscriptions that you update. So, it is possible, from a code-standpoint.